# ngIf can reference variable in nested ngFor in Angular 1.5. How to achieve the same in Angular 10?

Tags: angular

The following code works in Angular 1.5. The <tr> element will only be rendered if the 'showFields' flag for that row key is enabled.

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngIf="showFields[row.key]">
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
      <td>{{row.key}}</td>
      <td>{{row.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Note that the 'row' variable from the ngFor is visible to the enclosing ngIf. This no longer works in Angular 2+ because the scope of the ngFor variable is now confined to the element. How could I achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just switch the `ngFor` and `ngIf`, like so:

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <tr *ngIf="showFields[row.key]">
        <td>{{row.key}}</td>
        <td>{{row.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Instead of using a separate `showFields` boolean array, you could also think about adding a new property showField to the row object, then you can simply check `*ngIf="row.showField"`, which prevents out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I did give that a try and it didn't work. But it turns out it didn't work for a different reason. My 'rows'  variable is an object rather than an array. So I needed to do this *ngFor="let row of rows | keyvalue" to make it work with Angular 10. Your answer is correct though as per the question asked. Thanks very much.

Comment: Also, showFields is an object, so no bounds issue there and it's contents is modified dynamically by the user clicking on toggles in the UI to show or hide fields. Appreciate the help though.